# Does lightning beta tags pass security review?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, appexchange, security-review

There is `lightning:tabset` and `lightning:tab` tags which are still in beta as of now.
If we use them while developing an app exchange product do they pass security review?
Can we use them in production?

Comment: There is no issue in security review.. but there are scalability concern using it : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161000/lightning-tags-in-beta

Comment: Thank you @Ayub